# [Issue on Integrating CICD Pipeline]-No hosted parallelism has been purchased or granted

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, uipath-robot, uipath-orchestrator

I want to integrate CICD Pipeline for Uipath in azure devops using external application in orchestrator by following this uipath link How to Implement CICD Pipeline Using Azure DevOps Pipelines | Community Blog
But when I build the pipeline and then try to run that, getting the following error.

##[error]No hosted parallelism has been purchased or granted. To request a free parallelism grant, please fill out the following form https://aka.ms/

Please help

Comment: Did you follow the link from the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the abuse of the free grant of parallel jobs, since earlier of last year, the free grant of parallel jobs will not be enabled by default in the new created Azure DevOps organization.

If you created a new organization, you need to send a request [here](https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request) to ask enabling the free grant of parallel jobs in your new organization. Normally, it could take 2-3 business days to respond to your request.

[image]

For more details, you can reference the document about "[**Configure and pay for parallel jobs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted)".

Answer (score 0):

You could also use your visual studio benefits. The visual studio benefits get you a free agents automatically. Here the link : https://my.visualstudio.com/getstarted

Once here, scroll to the Azure DevOps tile and click "Get Started", it will redirect to your Azure DevOps Organisation and you will see you can now run your jobs and will have a free parallel agent.[image]